# Get __TEXT and __DATA Dyld address mapping from within an executable

Tags: c++, macos, dyld, mach-o

To find the dyld address mapping of __TEXT and __DATA for my mach-o executable I set the environment variable DYLD_PRINT_SEGMENTS=1. This logs on the console where in memory the executable is mapped.

However, I need to find the address mapping of __TEXT and __DATA internally from within my executable. Is there some API for elegantly obtaining this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain this information with the [`getsectbyname()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/getsectbyname) function from the `<mach-o/getsect.h>` header.

Comment: Thanks... This returns the running section data of the parent process. I found you can use getsectbynamefromheader() to get the section data for a plug-in or other process running internally.